# How to validate a group of checkboxes and return an error message javascript

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I have a form with 4 checkboxes and I have to display an error message when the form is submitted if no boxes are checked. This is what I have so far and I just don't know where I am going wrong.

Im new to javascript. I have validate being onload with the body tag I have just included the necessary parts. Thanks in advance for any help.

```js
function validate() {
  var choice1 = document.getElementById("base_small");
  var choice2 = document.getElementById("base_medium");
  var choice3 = document.getElementById("base_large");
  var choice4 = document.getElementById("base_xlarge");

  if ((choice1 == "") && (choice2 == "") && (choice3 == "") && (choice4 == "")) {
    alert("Please choose a base")


    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<div class="form1">
  <h3>Please select a base size**:</h3>
  <form id="orderformbase" class="orderbase" onsubmit="return validate()">
    <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="base" value="base_small"    id="base_small">Small<span class="price"> £5</span></label>
    <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="base" value="base_medium" id="base_medium">Medium<span class="price"> £7.50</span></label>
    <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="base" value="base_large" id="base_large">Large<span class="price"> £10</span></label>
    <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="base" value="base_xlarge" id="base_xlarge">X-Large<span class="price"> £12.50</span></label>
</div>
<!-- form1 close -->
</form>
```

Comment: You retrieve the checkboxe inputs but do not verify their `checked` propertie (boolean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplest solution, iterate over your radio and check if already checked or not.

```html
<script> 
function validate() {
   var isValid=false;
   var radioLength = document.getElementsByName('base').length;
   for(var i =0;i < radioLength;i++){
 if(document.getElementsByName('base')[i].checked){
    isValid=true;
 }
   }

  if(!isValid){
     alert("Please choose a base")
     return false;
  }else{
     alert("valid data");
     document.getElementById('orderformbase').submit();
     return true;
  } 
     
}
</script>

<div class="form1">
<h3>Please select a base size**:</h3>
<form id="orderformbase" class="orderbase">
<label class="block"><input type="radio" name="base" value="base_small"    id="base_small">Small<span class="price"> £5</span></label>
<label class="block"><input type="radio" name="base" value="base_medium" id="base_medium">Medium<span class="price"> £7.50</span></label>
<label class="block"><input type="radio" name="base" value="base_large" id="base_large">Large<span class="price"> £10</span></label>
<label class="block"><input type="radio" name="base" value="base_xlarge" id="base_xlarge">X-Large<span class="price"> £12.50</span></label>
<input type="button" onclick="validate();" value="submit"/>
</div> 
</form>
```

Comment: You're my hero. Thanks alot! Have a lovely day my friend

Answer (score 0):

Validate a checkbox like this in JS:

```
if(!choice1.checked)
{
    alert('You must check a checkbox.');
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
  var choice1 = document.getElementById("base_small").checked;
  var choice2 = document.getElementById("base_medium").checked;
  var choice3 = document.getElementById("base_large").checked;
  var choice4 = document.getElementById("base_xlarge").checked;
 if ((choice1 == false) && (choice2 == false) && (choice3 == false) && (choice4 == false)) {
    alert("Please choose a base");
    return false;
  }
```

The **checked** property sets or returns the checked state of a checkbox.

Comment: Is this helped you? @AdamElsbury

Comment: It is displaying the error alert box but the script is running before the form is submitted, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code for your question.

```
/* GETTING ALL ELEMENTS INSIDE THE FORM */
var elements = document.getElementById("orderformbase").elements,
    isFormValid = false;
/* LOOPING ALL THE ELEMENTS INSIDE THE FORM */
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  /* CHECKING WHETHER ITS RADIO BUTTON AND ITS CHECKED, TO MAKE THE ISFORMVALID VARIABLE TO TRUE */
  if (elements[i].type && elements[i].type == "radio" && elements[i].checked) {
      isFormValid = true;
      break;
  }
}
/* CHECKING WHETHER FORM IS VALID OR NOT USING ABOVE PROCESS, IF ITS NOT VALID, SHOW BELOW ERROR MSG */
if (!isFormValid) {
    alert("Please choose a base");
}

<div class="form1">
  <h3>Please select a base size**:</h3>
  <form id="orderformbase" class="orderbase" onsubmit="return validate()">
    <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="base"  value="base_small"    id="base_small">Small<span class="price"> £5</span></label>
    <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="base" value="base_medium" id="base_medium">Medium<span class="price"> £7.50</span></label>
    <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="base" value="base_large" id="base_large">Large<span class="price"> £10</span></label>
    <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="base" value="base_xlarge" id="base_xlarge">X-Large<span class="price"> £12.50</span></label>

<!-- form1 close -->
</form></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a reference to the form using *this*, then use a selector to see if there's a checked radio button:

```js
function validate(form) {
  return !!form.querySelector('input[name=base]:checked'));
};
```

```html
<div class="form1">
  <h3>Please select a base size**:</h3>
  <form id="orderformbase" class="orderbase" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
    <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="base" value="base_small"    id="base_small">Small<span class="price"> £5</span></label>
    <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="base" value="base_medium" id="base_medium">Medium<span class="price"> £7.50</span></label>
    <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="base" value="base_large" id="base_large">Large<span class="price"> £10</span></label>
    <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="base" value="base_xlarge" id="base_xlarge">X-Large<span class="price"> £12.50</span></label>
</div>
<input type="submit">
<!-- form1 close -->
</form>
```

To support older browsers, you can loop over the radios to see if there's a checked one:

```js
function validate(form) {
  var radios = form.base;
  for (var i=0, iLen=radios.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (radios[i].checked) return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

```html
<div class="form1">
  <h3>Please select a base size**:</h3>
  <form id="orderformbase" class="orderbase" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
    <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="base" value="base_small"    id="base_small">Small<span class="price"> £5</span></label>
    <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="base" value="base_medium" id="base_medium">Medium<span class="price"> £7.50</span></label>
    <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="base" value="base_large" id="base_large">Large<span class="price"> £10</span></label>
    <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="base" value="base_xlarge" id="base_xlarge">X-Large<span class="price"> £12.50</span></label>
</div>
<input type="submit">
<!-- form1 close -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a button rather than a form submit.

**eg.**

```
<input type="button" />
```

rather than:

```
<input type="submit" />
```

and then ***programmatically*** submit the form, *only* if the condition is satisfied.

**Working Example:**

```js
var orderForm = document.getElementById('orderformbase');
var submitButton = orderForm.querySelector('input[type="button"]');

function validateForm() {
    
    var choice1 = document.getElementById("base_small").checked;
    var choice2 = document.getElementById("base_medium").checked;
    var choice3 = document.getElementById("base_large").checked;
    var choice4 = document.getElementById("base_xlarge").checked;

    if ((choice1 === false) && (choice2 === false) && (choice3 === false) && (choice4 === false)) {
        orderForm.classList.add('invalid');
        alert("Please choose a base");
    }

    else {
        orderForm.submit();
    }
}

submitButton.addEventListener('click', validateForm, false);
```

```css
input[type="button"] {
display: block;
margin: 12px auto;
}

#orderformbase.invalid {
color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

#orderformbase.invalid fieldset {
border: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="form1">
  <h3>Please select a base size**:</h3>
  <form id="orderformbase" class="orderbase">
<fieldset>
<legend>Base Sizes</legend>
    <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="base" value="base_small"    id="base_small">Small<span class="price"> £5</span></label>
    <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="base" value="base_medium" id="base_medium">Medium<span class="price"> £7.50</span></label>
    <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="base" value="base_large" id="base_large">Large<span class="price"> £10</span></label>
    <label class="block"><input type="radio" name="base" value="base_xlarge" id="base_xlarge">X-Large<span class="price"> £12.50</span></label>
</fieldset>
<input type="button" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your if condition should be this:

```
if((choice1.checked="None")&&(choice2.checked="None")&&(choice3.checked="None")&&(choice4.checked="None"))
```